# Docker Container still running after stop and remove

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm currently trying to learn docker basics.

I'm looking to get used to the CLI. So I pulled/ran some docker containers, namely an Apache Http Server and the getting started container. Afterwards, I ran `docker ps`, checked the IDs and ran

```
docker stop <id> 
docker rm <id>
```

Now I tried setting up a local postgres db. So I pulled postgres and pgadmin and made them run on ports 5432 and 80 respectively.

Thinking, it should all be set up, i visited localhost:80 and was welcomed by the getting started page again. Despite running stop and rm.

I thought maybe something went wrong and the ports weren't freed by Docker or something similar. So I completely restarted the docker service and stopped every process related to Docker I could find. Finally I restarted my computer.
Looking at the task manager now, I could not find any traces of Docker processes or such running on my machine. Despite that, if i visit localhost:80 I am still greeted with the getting started page. And visiting localhost:8080 I am still greeted with Apaches "It works!" message.

I am at a loss here, since there is no Docker Service running, yet I am still accessing the Apache Server running locally.

**Edit 1:** I do not have any running servers on my local machine. I never installed, nor started any Apache http servers on my machine.

Hopefully reproducible example (the exact steps I took):

```
docker pull httpd
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting started
```

Verify, that getting started is running on localhost:80

```
# This shows the getting started process running with id <id>
docker ps
# Stopping and removing the process
docker stop <id>
docker rm <id>
# Remove the getting started image
docker images rm <your_id>
```

Restart PC, go to localhost:80.
For me, this shows the getting started page again.

Then close any processes related to Docker (e.g. Docker Desktop, etc). Make sure, that com.Docker.backend.exe is also not running.

Comment: Please share more details. Have you checked whether there is any other server installed on your computer?

Comment: A [mcve] including any relevant application source code would be really helpful.  How did you initially start the containers?  Are the database containers required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: See edit 1 for the exact steps i took

Comment: after you do a restart of you machine do a `docker ps` again. If this doesn't show any running containers (which I presume it doesn't, because docker container usually don't autostart themselves) it's not a docker container runnig but some local server ... Also try clearing the browser cache ...

Comment: More Details Needed. Anyways you can try 'docker builder prune -f' it used to deleted cache image object.

Comment: Also this method clears memory space occupied by container into your system as well. First check if you have any running container by 'docker ps' and if gets nothing then try if there are any stopped container by 'docker container ls -a', if gets nothing then no container present. For clear everything you can use 'docker system prune' but it removes everything(be cautious while using this)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Clearing the browser cache fixed it for me. (as recommended by @derpischer)

For example in firefox: go to settings. Under "Cookies and Site Data", use the "Clear Data" button and make sure "Cached Web Content" is selected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).